# SASS variables and inheritance

Tags: css, sass, nested

Suppose I have two virtually identical HTML structures, but with different `class` names. They only differ by a few variables, like `width` and `height`. By using SASS/SCSS variables I thought I could do something like this:

```
.widget-a {
    $width: 50px;
}

.widget-b {
    $width: 100px;
}

.widget-a,
.widget-b {
    button {
        background: red;
        width: $width;
    }
}
```

This would let me write a single piece of SASS nested code for both widgets a and b. However, variables are only visible inside a nested scope, so SASS returns 'variable undefined' errors. Of course I could rewrite it by simply doing something like:

```
.widget-a,
.widget-b {
    button {
        background: red;
    }
}

.widget-a {
    button {
        width: 50px;
    }
}

.widget-b {
    button {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

But that seems pretty cumbersome. Is there any other method of making this work?

Answer (score 1):

Variables in SASS are only scoped to the block they appear in. Your first `.widget-a` declaration and the one declaring both A and B are two separate scopes. You'll have to do something like this (assuming you need to use the widths more than once):

```
$wbackground: red;

.widget-a {
    $wawidth: 50px; /* widget A width */
    button {
        background: $wbackground;
        width: $wawidth;
    }
}

.widget-b {
    $wbwidth: 100px; /* widget B width */
    button {
        background: $wbackground;
        width: $wbwidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then i need to restate all declarations, which isn't very DRY. I was hoping there would be an easier solution that didn't require restating all rules.

Comment: @Husky Sorry I don't know of any other way. Perhaps you can contact the SASS team and ask them to consider what you want as a new feature?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just did that.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem, this is how I'm going to try to solve it... (this works)

```
@mixin foo($type:"default")
  .mClass
    $bg: inherit
    @if $type == "banana"
      $bg: yellow

    background: $bg

.firstClass
  @include foo
.secondClass
  @include foo("banana")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by using a mixin.

```
@mixin button($width){
  button{
    background:red;
    width:$width;
  }
}

.widget-a{ @include button(50px);  }

.widget-b{ @include button(100px); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the advantage of creating a mixin only for this specific situation, it is hardly useful on a couple of occasions, but it is just my opinion.

Anyway, I've created a mixin, just for fun. I think that it can help you to deal with this specific situation. Here is the **[mixin](https://gist.github.com/Aloge/7418775)** and I'm going to try to explain how it works:

```
@include button($selectors, $property, $values, $child: false) {
  // Common properties that are included in all $selectors  
}
```

This mixin takes four parameters:

- `$selectors`: List of selectors, in your case, `.widget-a` and `.widget-b`, they should be enclosed in quotes.
- `$property`: Here you should enter the name of the property, in your case `width`
- `$values`: Values ​​are, as the name implies , the values of the property for each selector
- `$child`: Here you can enter the name of a child, this is optional.
- Into the brackets `{}` you should write all the properties that you want to include in all `$parameters`
- The order of each selector must match the order of their corresponding value

So, here's an example using this mixin to solve your problem. This is the `@include`:

```
@include (".widget-a" ".widget-b", width, 50px 100px, button) {
  background: red;
}
```

And this, the code that returns:

```
.widget-a button, .widget-b button {
  background: red; }

.widget-a button {
  width: 50px; }

.widget-b button {
  width: 100px; }
```

This is another way to achieve the same result:

```
@include button(".widget-a .button" ".widget-b .button", width, 50px 100px)  {
  background: red;
}
```

**Download the mixin [here](https://gist.github.com/Aloge/7418775)**